# SQL Server 2008. Order with repeated only if previous is different

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have this table:

```
Price   | OrderDate   | OrderID
--------+-------------+-----
5.50000 | 2017-11-02  | 77319 
5.30000 | 2017-11-02  | 77320
5.50000 | 2017-11-09  | 77463
5.50000 | 2017-11-16  | 77633
5.50000 | 2017-11-23  | 77839
5.25000 | 2017-11-23  | 77840
5.35000 | 2017-11-30  | 78012
5.50000 | 2017-12-07  | 78138
5.50000 | 2017-12-14  | 78283
```

---

I need to get this result

```
Price   | OrderDate   | OrderID
--------+-------------+--------
5.50000  2017-11-02     77319 
5.30000  2017-11-02     77320
5.50000  2017-11-09     77463
5.25000  2017-11-23     77840
5.35000  2017-11-30     78012
5.50000  2017-12-07     78138
```

The values in bold, i need to group and only get 1 row. The order of the table should be like the result.

I don't have a clue on how to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: to group them into 1 record, you need some logic for determining which OrderID and OrderDate to take.

Comment: additionally, "...Order only if previous is diiferent..." - Previous what? Price?

Comment: Why is ID 77633 not included in the result? Edit: Nevermind, you are only looking at the price and not the Price/OrderDate combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can use `lag()`:

```
with data as (
    select *, lag(Price) over (order by OrderId) as lastPrice
    from T
)
select *
from data
where coalesce(Price, -1) <> lastPrice;
```

Otherwise, assuming you can use `cross apply`:

```
select t.*
from T t cross apply (
    select max(OrderId) priorOrderId from T t2 where t2.OrderId < t.OrderId
) left outer join T t3 on t3.OrderId = t2.priorOrderId
where coalesce(t3.Price, -1) <> t.Price;
```

Which otherwise can still be rewritten:

```
with data as (
    select *, (select max(OrderID from T t2 where t2.OrderId < t.OrderId) as priorOrderId
    from T t
)
select d.*
from data d left outer join T t on t.OrderId = d.priorOrderId
where coalesce(t.Price, -1) <> d.Price;
```

Comment: i cant use lag(), im using sql server 2008

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `lag` window function to get the price of the previous row, and omit the rows where the price didn't change:

```
SELECT   price, orderid, orderdate
FROM     (SELECT price, orderid, orderdate,
                 LAG(price) OVER(ORDER BY orderid ASC) AS prev_price
          FROM   mytable)
WHERE    price <> prev_price OR prev_price IS NULL
ORDER BY orderid ASC
```

Comment: i was reading about LAG, but in sql server 2008  isnt available :(

Answer (score 1):

If your sql server version is 2008 and didn't support  `LAG` window function.

You can try to use a subquery instead of `LAG` window function.

```
SELECT Price,OrderDate,OrderID 
FROM (
    SELECT *,(select top 1 Price FROM T tt where tt.OrderID < t1.OrderID order by tt.OrderID desc) preval
    FROM T t1
) t1
WHERE preval <> Price or preval IS NULL
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b92d96b796fcc5481fa9ffb79724a75b)

Answer (score 0):

This is not efficient but it might be easy to understand and in real life you just might not see it inefficiencies.

```
SELECT
    Price
    ,OrderDate
    ,OrderID
FROM TableName
WHERE Price <> ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Price FROM TableName T2 WHERE T2.OrderID < TableName.OrderID ORDER BY OrderID DESC), -1)
```

The guts are in the WHERE clause.  For each record it finds the price of the previous record based on [OrderID]  If they are different, it includes them.  You have to include ISNULL though because the first record does not have a previous record.